# Promise from observable doesn't wait to be fulfilled

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have written a function that will get the IMDB ratings of an IMDB ID through an API.
This is the function to which i pass the IMDB ID

```
async function movieDetails(ID){
    let ratings= await getDetails(ID);
    return ratings;
}
```

And this is the function that returns the IMDB ratings.

```
const getDetails = val =>{
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${val}&plot=full&apikey=${APIKey}`)
    .then(e => e.json())
    .catch(err => console.log(err)))
    .map(e => e.imdbRating)
    .subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x);
        return x;
    }, e => console.error(e));
}
```

But this function is returning a promise object instead of IMDB rating.
And this is the output which i get on the console.

> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
>
> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
>
> 8.1
>
> 7.3

8.1 and 7.3 are the values from the console statement in getDeatils() which is what i am returning.
And the promise object are printed when movieDetails() is called.
Can anyonebody point me out, what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: `.then(e => e.json())` change to `.then(e => return e.json())`

Comment: @messerbill No. `=>` without a following block implies a  return with arrow function syntax...

Comment: really? lol thanks...

Comment: @messerbill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I think, arrow function doesn't need return statement for a single line body without braces

Comment: Anyone of you knows what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Please show us where and how you placed the `console.log` statements "*when movieDetails() is called*" - because those are the important ones that don't work.

Comment: Why are you using an observable? Just using promises would be much simpler.

Comment: okay i now tried with just promises..still i am getting the same output on console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDetails` function returns `subscription`, and in `movieDetails` you are `await`ing those subscription. In short, it doesn't work.

When you subscribe into created observable you get subscription to control its lifecycle. Those subscription doesn't do anything with values of observables.

```
const obs = Observable.from(...) //obs is Observable
const subs = obs.subscribe((x) => console.log(x)); //subs is Subscription

// subs.unsubscribe(); //when you want to unsubscribe even source does not completes
```

Secondly, you can't directly `await` Observables - await keyword is for Promise. In Observables, observer is way to access values (function supplied in `subscribe`). If you should use await, convert Observables into `toPromise` and get only latest number - otherwise, just return observable in `getDetail` then access values via observer is way to go.